# Maple tree disease

Tags: trees, diagnosis, leaves, maple

[image]

Maple tree did not produce leaves this Spring and now has these white fluffy balls. Only the bottom branch has leaves left. Can anyone help me save this tree?

These fluffy things are only visible in early morning.I got a good close up and notice tiny bugs in the web

[image: close up]

Comment: Probably not if it's dead except one branch. A picture would be helpful, but  most likely the tree is beyond saving from your text description.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of those for sure! I just had this problem but not as bad. There were worms inside of the white balls. They will eat your tree right up. An effective way is to burn them. I use a little lighter fluid and it takes them down fast. You can also use some chemical but not too sure what you could use. Burning is just as effective in my option.

Note: Do this only if it is a bug or worm. Do not light the tree on fire. Small amounts and small areas at a time. Nothing more. Good luck!